# Azure AD B2C - Multi Tenant Applicatication using custom Flows

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, orchardcore

I am building a .NET multi tenant application with Orchard Core. I am using Azure AD B2C custom policies for authentication. Since it is a multitenant application I have different authentication mechanism for different tenant.

```
For Eg: 
Tenant A wants to use Facebook Auth 
Tenant B wants to use Google Auth 
Tenant C wants to use Microsoft Auth
```

Is there any way that by using url itself

```
https://myapp/tenantA
https://myapp/tenantB
https://myapp/tenantC
```

to achieve this functionality.

If we can achieve should we do it Via .NET code or should we configure something in Custom Policies in Azure AD B2C?